# amdgpu drivers not loading on Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, amd-graphics

After a sudden drop in performance and some googling around, I found that my laptop is not loading the `amdgpu` drivers. I have to boot with `nomodeset`, otherwise the laptop will not start.

Some potentially helpful information:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcc00000-fcc7ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15d8] (rev c4)
```

```
$ lsmod | grep amdgpu
```

```
$ grep -E 'amdgpu|radeon' /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist radeonfb
```

Can any one help me get them back in use?

Comment: also having literally this problem on a HP Elitebook 745 G6 with a fresh Xubuntu 22.04.2 - amdgpu just won't load. Even tried Liquorix kernel 6.4.15, no dice.

CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 3500U w/ Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx, codename Picasso.
the picasso firmware appears to be present.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this on my HP Elitebook 745 G6, which was having the precise same problem.

What I did:

1. Remove "nomodeset".
2. In the BIOS, set "Legacy Boot Disable and Secure Boot Enable".
3. Remove Liquorix, it doesn't have the secure boot shim.

sudo lshw -c video confirms that I'm using amdgpu.

That's it. I have no idea why it worked, but it did. Typing this response from the 745 :-)